# Can't process REST POST requests to Wildfly 25 (and newer)

Tags: java, rest, wildfly, resteasy

Since Wildfly 25.0.0 my app has stopped working and cannot get it to work with latest WF versions. Last version my app worked properly on is 24.0.1.Final.

I have RESTful interface with POST endpoints but anytime I send POST request (with json body) the flow throws `NullPointerException` from class `org.jboss.resteasy.core.providerfactory.ResteasyProviderFactoryImpl` method:

```
protected MediaTypeMap<SortedKey<MessageBodyReader>> getServerMessageBodyReaders()
   {
      return serverHelper.getMessageBodyReaders();
   }
```

because the `serverHelper` is null. This is internal class of Resteasy lib implementation of rest api that Wildfly utilises. It seems like an issue with initialisation inside of WF and I can't identify what is missing. I have custom `Provider` implementation that worked properly for json unmarshaling. But now the flow breaks even sooner before it reaches the provider class.

```
@Provider
@Dependent
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class GsonProvider<T> implements MessageBodyWriter<T>, MessageBodyReader<T> {

    @Inject
    @Api
    private Gson gson;

    @Override
    public boolean isWriteable(Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
        return MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE.isCompatible(mediaType);
    }

    @Override
    public long getSize(T t, Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
        return -1;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeTo(T t, Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType, MultivaluedMap<String, Object> httpHeaders, OutputStream entityStream) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
        try (Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(entityStream)) {
            gson.toJson(t, writer);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isReadable(Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
        return MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE.isCompatible(mediaType);
    }

    @Override
    public T readFrom(Class<T> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType, MultivaluedMap<String, String> httpHeaders, InputStream entityStream) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
        try (Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(entityStream)) {
            return gson.fromJson(reader, type);
        }
    }
}
```

GET requests that produce json work with the custom provider without any problem. Just the POST requests with body when the correct message body reader must be identified and used end with this NPE.

deps in my root pom

```
<dependencyManagement>
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wildfly.bom</groupId>
        <artifactId>wildfly-jakartaee8-with-tools</artifactId>
        <version>26.1.0.Final</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
  <dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

deps in war pom

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-core</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

this issue applies from WF version 25.0.0.Final and later (currently 26.1.0.Final). There was a change between 24 and 25 in resteasy deps when `resteasy-jaxrs` got replaced by `resteasy-core`, `resteasy-core-spi` etc. in WF boms. I haven't been able to figure out how to fix the NPE since then.

exception stack trace:

```
org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ReaderException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MessageBodyParameterInjector.inject(MessageBodyParameterInjector.java:250)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.PropertyInjectorImpl.inject(PropertyInjectorImpl.java:145)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.cdi.JaxrsInjectionTarget.inject(JaxrsInjectionTarget.java:74)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.create(ManagedBean.java:161)
    at org.jboss.weld.contexts.AbstractContext.get(AbstractContext.java:96)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$DefaultContextualInstanceStrategy.get(ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:100)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$CachingContextualInstanceStrategy.get(ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:177)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstance.get(ContextualInstance.java:50)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ContextBeanInstance.getInstance(ContextBeanInstance.java:102)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.getInstance(ProxyMethodHandler.java:131)
    at io.whalebone.publicapi.rest.endpoint.event.EventsScrollSearchEndpoint$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.search(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:170)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:130)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.internalInvokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:660)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTargetAfterFilter(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:524)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.lambda$invokeOnTarget$2(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:474)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:364)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:476)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:434)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:408)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:69)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:492)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$invoke$4(SynchronousDispatcher.java:261)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$preprocess$0(SynchronousDispatcher.java:161)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:364)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.preprocess(SynchronousDispatcher.java:164)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:247)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:249)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:60)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
    at io.opentracing.contrib.jaxrs2.server.SpanFinishingFilter.doFilter(SpanFinishingFilter.java:52)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.ElytronRunAsHandler.lambda$handleRequest$1(ElytronRunAsHandler.java:68)
    at org.wildfly.security.auth.server.FlexibleIdentityAssociation.runAsFunctionEx(FlexibleIdentityAssociation.java:103)
    at org.wildfly.security.auth.server.Scoped.runAsFunctionEx(Scoped.java:161)
    at org.wildfly.security.auth.server.Scoped.runAs(Scoped.java:73)
    at org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.ElytronRunAsHandler.handleRequest(ElytronRunAsHandler.java:67)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:117)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.servlet.CleanUpHandler.handleRequest(CleanUpHandler.java:38)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.SendErrorPageHandler.handleRequest(SendErrorPageHandler.java:52)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:275)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:79)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:134)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1544)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1544)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1544)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1544)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:255)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:79)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:100)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:387)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:852)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1348)
    at org.xnio.XnioWorker$WorkerThreadFactory$1$1.run(XnioWorker.java:1280)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.providerfactory.ResteasyProviderFactoryImpl.getServerMessageBodyReaders(ResteasyProviderFactoryImpl.java:294)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.providerfactory.ResteasyProviderFactoryImpl.getServerMessageBodyReader(ResteasyProviderFactoryImpl.java:532)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.ServerReaderInterceptorContext.resolveReader(ServerReaderInterceptorContext.java:46)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.getReader(AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.java:130)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.proceed(AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.java:75)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.security.doseta.DigitalVerificationInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(DigitalVerificationInterceptor.java:36)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.proceed(AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.java:88)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MessageBodyParameterInjector.inject(MessageBodyParameterInjector.java:213)
    ... 83 more
```

Comment: Can you post the stack trace? It's hard to tell where the issue might be without that. There was an upgrade from 3.15 to 4.7 in WildFly 25.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins stack trace added

Comment: This looks every strange. I don't see how it could be `null`. It's always assigned a value. Do you by chance have some kind of reproducer?